# CSS sprites - multiple calls

Tags: css

Is it wrong to call the sprite image for every instance it is needed in css? How does the browser handle this, is it only being loaded once?

Example:

```
.box1{ background: url('../img/sprite.png') 0 0 no-repeat; }
.box2{ background: url('../img/sprite.png') 0 -20px no-repeat; }
.btn{ background: url('../img/sprite.png') -100px -60px no-repeat; }
```

I have seen some examples where you call the sprite once and just alter the background position.

Example:

```
#myDiv{ background: url('../img/sprite.png') 0 0 no-repeat; }
#myDiv .box2{ background-position: 0 -20px; }
```

Comment: is it only being loaded once? yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing wrong with that technique is that your CSS will have redundant code, which makes it larger (in terms of bytes) than it needs to be.

It does not load the background image more than once. You can confirm this by opening your developer tools and watching the network tab.

Comment: Just to clarify, this technique doesn't make CSS redundant IMO. Specifying background image for all elements in one rule (having comma separated selector) and then only changing the `background-position` makes it more concise IMO. If one produces redundant CSS with one technique, he's going to produce redundant CSS anyway ;)

Comment: I think it's acceptable to have redundant selectors, but the styles themselves should be defined once to avoid error and simplify maintenance. Whether that's still redundant is debatable.

Answer (score 1):

The background image will only be downloaded once.

To test this you can check to see what resources are being downloaded in Chrome by doing the following:

1. navigate to the webpage
2. right click somewhere on the page
3. click inspect element
4. click on the network tab
5. refresh the page

All the resources that are are loaded will show up in this list.

Also, you can DRY up your CSS like this:

```
.box1, .box2, .btn{ background-image: url('../img/sprite.png') }
.box1{ background-position: 0 0 no-repeat; }
.box2{ background-position: 0 -20px no-repeat; }
.btn{ background-position: -100px -60px no-repeat; }
```